# Spring Integration HttpServerErrorException$InternalServerError: 500 : No reply received within timeout

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, dsl

I am trying to copy some data to another channel using wireTap. this is my code:

```
 @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow() {
     
            return IntegrationFlows.from(Http.inboundGateway("/foo")
                            .requestMapping(m -> m.methods(HttpMethod.POST)
                    .transform(Transformers.objectToString())
                    .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerExpression())
                    .transform(new ObjectTransformation()).wireTap("subChannel")
                    .get();
    }
```

I have made a subscribtion channel and a loggerHandler as well

```
 @Bean
    public SubscribableChannel subscribeChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.publishSubscribe("subChannel")
                .get();
    }


    public LoggingHandler logger() {
        LoggingHandler logger = new LoggingHandler(Level.INFO);
        return logger;
    }
```

I also created a flow to log the copied data :

```
 @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow subscribeFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("subChannel")
                .handle(logger()).get();
    }
```

I am getting an error that there is no reply :

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException$InternalServerError: 500 : "No reply received within timeout"
```

I don't know where it is going wrong, any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**
The fact that i am using the wireTap() at the end of the flow makes the flow goes wrong, because there is no reply on default. so i had to add .bridge() to the flow.
The flow should be as below :

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow() {
     
            return IntegrationFlows.from(Http.inboundGateway("/foo")
                            .requestMapping(m -> m.methods(HttpMethod.POST)
                    .transform(Transformers.objectToString())
                    .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerExpression())
                    .transform(new ObjectTransformation()).wireTap("subChannel").bridge()
                    .get();
    }
```

check this post
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62673629/timeout-on-replychannel-when-wiretap-is-used#:~:text=The%20behavior%20is,more%20in%20docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62673629/timeout-on-replychannel-when-wiretap-is-used#:%7E:text=The%20behavior%20is,more%20in%20docs)

Comment: That's correct. We have an opened issue to address this problem: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3615